# beforeRouteUpdate not recognizing function

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

When I try to call `this.getData()` in `beforeRouteUpdate` it just spits out this error

> "TypeError: this.getData is not a function"

From looking at other peoples examples this work, but they weren't using async/await.

```html
<script>
export default {
  async beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next) {
    await this.getData()
    next()
  },
  data() {
    return {
      word: null,
    }
  },
  async created() {
    await this.getData()
  },
  methods: {
    async getData() {
      const resp = await axios.get(
        'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/word/' + this.$route.params.word,
        { validateStatus: false }
      )

      console.log(resp)
      switch (resp.status) {
        case 200:
          this.word = {
            word: resp.data.word,
            definition: resp.data.definition,
          }
          break
        case 404:
          this.word = null
          break
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Strange indeed. Does it give you something if you `console.log(this)`? It should be available.

Answer (score 0):

The concept you want use it, is called "prefetch".
It's better use this solution:

```
  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    axios.get(
        'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/word/' + this.$route.params.word,
        {validateStatus: false}
    )
        .then(resp => {
          next()
        })
        .catch(error => {
        })
  },

  beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next) {
    axios.get(
        'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/word/' + this.$route.params.word,
        {validateStatus: false}
    )
        .then(resp => {
          next()
        })
        .catch(error => {
        })
  }
```

**NOTE 1:** You don't access to `this` in `beforeRouteEnter` (to use `methods`). Because your component doesn't mounted yet.

**NOTE 2:** To avoid fetch duplication (DRY principle), you can modularize fetching (like vuex actions) and call it.

Comment: This works but how do i change this.word as I am unable to change it here (by calling this.word = x)

Comment: @stackoverflowuser You can use callback argument in next, It provides access to your component. See [this](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#using-the-options-api)